# How to call a function from a local helper in <img src

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, php-5.4, jquery, phtml

This is my code to take the images from the server using ASIN , the database only has the SKU and no ASIN.

```
<?php
    class Bundle_LocalHelpers_Helper extends Mage_core_Helper_Abstract{

    public function getImageUrl($product)
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $sku = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(), 'sku', $storeId);
    $asin = substr($sku,0,10);

    if ($sku != null) {
        $asin = $product->getAsin();
    }
        return "http://productimages.bundle.com/images/$asin.jpg";
    }
    else
    {
        return error;
    }
 }
?>
```

I would like to use the owl-carousel which is a slider for the product images, so I am using this code:

```
 <?php
 /**
 * @var Bundle_LocalHelpers_Helper_Basic $localHelper
 */
    $localHelper = Mage::helper('localhelper/basic');
 ?>
 <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
 <?php

   $categoryId = 2; // this is the category holding your products  
   $products = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($categoryId) //load the category
           ->getProductCollection() // and the products
           ->addAttributeToSelect('image'); // tell Magento which attributes to get

     foreach ($products as $product) ?> { // iterate through the entire   collection
    <div class="item">
    <img src="<?php echo $localHelper->getImageUrl($product);?>">
    </div>  // print the image url inside of the required Owl markup
  }
  ?>
 </div>

<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    items : 4,
    lazyLoad : true,
    navigation : true
  }); 

});
```

When I call the function in my phtml file the main content and footer disappears and the question is how can I call this function so it returns the images?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the helper is a file Basic.php, located in app/code/local/Bundle/LocalHelpers/Helper/Basic.php, you have to rename the class: change this

```
class Bundle_LocalHelpers_Helper extends Mage_core_Helper_Abstract{
```

to

```
class Bundle_LocalHelpers_Helper_Basic extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
```

You must also have this section in your module's config.xml:

```
<helpers>
  <localhelpers>
    <class>Bundle_LocalHelpers_Helper</class>
  </localhelpers>
</helpers
```

Comment: Sorry maybe my question wasn't to precise , I had the config however this wasn't the problem . I have sorted it already but Thank you !

Comment: Good for you, but please post & accept an answer if you have solved the problem.